# How to push multiple images in an array?

Tags: arrays, image, react-native

I'm creating a React Native application. I want to create an image array because I need to upload them to the server. But when I upload multiple images they are not storing like an array. every time the **imagesQueue** array has only one image.

my code as follows.

```
const [filePath, setFilePath] = useState({
        imagesQueue: []
    });

const chooseFile = () => {
    const options = {
        title: 'Select an option',
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'images',
        },
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        // console.log('Response = ', response);
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else {
            // let source = response;
            // You can also display the image using data:
            let source = {
                uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data
            };
            setFilePath({
                ...filePath,
                imagesQueue: [source],
            });
            console.log("stored item : " + filePath.imagesQueue);
        }
    });
};
```

How to store multiple images in the same state. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the data probably will store in `formData` - it's easy format for later passing it to BE.

firstly You need store somewhere those data:

```
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
```

Later there is possibility to use `.concat()` - that function connects 2 arrays:

```
  setSelectedFiles(((prevState) => prevState.concat(fileData)));
```

And in the last step, You need to pass those data to Your form:

```
const formData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
  formData.append('Files', selectedFiles[i].File);
}
```